# python httplib httpexception error codes

Tags: python, http, exception, tcp

Does httplib.HTTPException have error codes?  If so how do I get at them from the exception instance?  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `httplib` module doesn't use exceptions to convey HTTP responses, just genuine errors (invalid HTTP responses, broken headers, invalid status codes, prematurely broken connections, etc.) Most of the httplib.HTTPException subclasses just have an associated message string (stored in the `args` attribute), if even that. `httplib.HTTPException` itself may have an "errno" value as the first entry in `args` (when raised through httplib.FakeSocket) but it's not a HTTP error code.

The HTTP response codes are conveyed through the `httplib.HTTPConnection` object, though; the `getresponse` method will (usually) return a `HTTPResponse` instance with a `status` attribute set to the HTTP response code, and a `reason` attribute set to the text version of it. This includes error codes like `404` and `500`. I say "usually" because you (or a library you use) can override `httplib.HTTPConnection.response_class` to return something else.